# Dart remove square brackets and add single quotation mark

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of strings pulled from database as a string

```
[name 1, name2, name3, ...]
```

i am trying to convert it to this:

```
'name 1', 'name2', 'name3', '...'
```

so far no success.
method with which i am getting data. The method is just fine since I am using it beforehand for other part of code.

```
  Future<List<String>> getNames() async {
    var url = _api + "get_names.php?key=" + _key;
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    var resp = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return resp.map<String>((m) => m['names'] as String).toList();
  }
```

list is pulled from database as a String.

Basicaly I am using a part of formbuilder code which uses initialValue as dynamic.
so if I set initialValue: [widget.names] and the widget.names contains 'name1','name2' it is ok
if it is a list of string but It needs to be ofcourse single or double quoted and seperated with comma.

Thank you

Comment: the response you get from db is not proerly formatted. it should return something like `['name 1','name 2','...']`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
void main() {
  final input = '[name 1, name2, name3, ...]';
  final removedBrackets = input.substring(1, input.length - 1);
  final parts = removedBrackets.split(', ');
  
  var joined = parts.map((part) => "'$part'").join(', ');
  
  print(joined);
}
```

Using: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/split.html

Prints:

```
'name 1', 'name2', 'name3', '...'
```

That said... maybe you should find a better way to get your data. Maybe as Json or something, so you don't have to reinvent serialization. What happens for example if "name 1" has a comma in it? Or let's say it's [d'Artagnan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Three_Musketeers)?

Comment: well you are right, but there will be no commas and so on in names. We don't have that kind of names and it will be disabled in input field. Thanks this works just fine

Comment: A note for the unwary (like me). In the example, the input is already a string. I had to convert a list to a string first, so tried this in one line `String output = mylist.toString().substring(1, mylist-1)` ... but of course the length of the string is much larger than the length of the list it is made from.  Cue mild confusion when the output string was too short, even though when I printed the list it was clearly 10 items long